# PHP PDO: Displaying errors

Tags: php, pdo

Do I need to use the try and catch block to display errors with PHP's PDO extension?

For example, with mysql you can usally do something like:

```
if ( ! $query)
{
    die('Oh noes!');
}
```

Comment: You never *need* to use try/catch anywhere, but it's generally a good idea if you want to handle exceptions gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

You can choose what PDO does with errors via PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE:

```
$pdo->setAttribute (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING); // Raise E_WARNING.
$pdo->setAttribute (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT); // Sets error codes.
// or
$pdo->setAttribute (PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // throws exception
```

Answer (score 1):

PDO by default supports it's own Exception Class, `PDOException`.

There should be no reason why you cannot use:

```
try{
    $query = $db->prepare(...);
    if( !$query ){
        throw new Exception('Query Failed');
    }
}
catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

The reason I only catch `Exception` is because `PDOException` is a child of Exception. Catching the Parent will catch ALL children.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static function qry($sql) {
    try {
    $statement = $db_handle->prepare($sql);
    $retval = $statement->execute();
    if($statement->rowCount() >= 1) { 
        //do something               
    }else {
    $errors = $statement->errorInfo();
    echo $errors[2] . ", " . $errors[1] . " ," . $errors[0];
}
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a try catch statement, you still can use this kind of code :

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table");
if(!$query->execute()) {
   print_r($query->errorInfo());
}
```